# Correlation matrix by group

Tags: r, plyr, correlation, hmisc

This is my data frame

```
df <- structure(list(g1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "C"), class = "factor"), g2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), v1 = 1:10, v2 = c(5, 5, 6, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 9, 8), v3 = c(29, 10, 56, 93, 20, 14, 12, 87, 67, 37)), .Names = c("g1", "g2",  "v1", "v2", "v3"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

   g1 g2 v1 v2 v3
1   A  a  1  5 29
2   A  a  2  5 10
3   A  a  3  6 56
4   A  b  4  2 93
5   A  b  5  4 20
6   C  a  6  4 14
7   C  a  7  2 12
8   C  b  8  1 87
9   C  b  9  9 67
10  C  b 10  8 37
```

I'd like to create a correlation matrix of v1, v2 and v3 for each combination of groups g1 and g2 (Aa, Ab, Ca, Cb in this case). So I'd like to use package Hmisc and combine with plyr

```
library(Hmisc)
library(plyr)
```

This works (ignoring groups though of course):

```
rcorr(as.matrix(df[,3:5]), type="pearson")
```

But this does not:

```
cor.matrix <- dlply(df, .(g1,g2), rcorr(as.matrix(df[,3:5]), type="pearson"))
Error:attempt to apply non-function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How 'bout this? `by(df, INDICES = list(df$g1, df$g2), FUN = function(x) cor(x[, c("v1", "v2", "v3")]))`

Comment: That works great, thanks, however, the reason why I wanted to use `rcorr` from Hmisc is that it also generates a matrix with p-values. I don't think this is possible with `cor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works if you have more than 4 observations per group (hence why I `rbind`ed your `df` with an additional 2 more `df`):

```
df <- structure(list(g1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    .Label = c("A", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    g2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    v1 = 1:10, v2 = c(5, 5, 6, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 9, 8), 
    v3 = c(29, 10, 56, 93, 20, 14, 12, 87, 67, 37)), 
    .Names = c("g1", "g2",  "v1", "v2", "v3"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
    class = "data.frame")


df <- rbind(df, df, df)

library(Hmisc)
lapply(split(df, df[, 1:2]), function(x) {
    rcorr(as.matrix(x[,3:5]), type="pearson")
})
```

**EDIT**  This works:

```
dlply(df, .(g1,g2), function(x) rcorr(as.matrix(x[,3:5]), type="pearson"))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Still, do you have an explanation why `dlply` does not work? Just curious ;)